# SVG/XAML: Defining a path which looks like an arrow

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, svg

I'm trying to use SVG (really XAML) to define a path which looks like a downwards pointing arrow.

```
   |
   |
\  |  /
 \ | /
  \ /
   `
```

It is super-important that the edge of the arrow is sharp. I have tried with various combinations of `M`, `L` and `z` with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having done some research, I don't think such a thing is possible to do with a single path *easily*. I did manage to solve it all by finding a library of XAML arrows and then doing some trickery to rotate the arrow I wanted the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the Marker element:

[painting_Markers](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#Markers)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about SVG but this will produce a sharp edge in XAML (tested in XAML Crancher)

```
<Path Data="M 10 0 L 10 20 0 10 0 15 12.5 27.5 25 15 25 10 15 20 15 0 z" Stroke="Black"/>
```

Comment: Indeed, how did you do it? Any particular software or online source?

Comment: @Hannish I just typed it by hand, its just a list of commands and coordinates, for more complex shapes I use graph paper

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/painting/linejoin.svg) from the SVG spec. You may want to tweak the ['stroke-miterlimit' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeMiterlimitProperty) depending on the sharpness of the corner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use something like inkscape and design the arrow (just draw a line, select it, go to object > filling / contour > pattern and contourline > endmarker)
then save as pdf, rename the *.pdf to *.ai, open blend and import the ai file as adobe illustrator.
It's a bit difficult, but I still prefer it over using blend.
(i translated from german, so some menu items might be slightly different)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer.

You (and your readers) should note the advent of Raphael (If they have not already) and also my offering for the SVG world.

I have been working for a year with Raphael and SVG. This link to my homepage might interest you (To those who are still listening and/or switched on to the power of Inkscape/Cross Browser SVG)

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/

This home page is a hybrid of the W3C SVG recommendations and the javascript library and beneath it are all the resources to get up and running quickly with SVG and Raphael.

Regards Chasbeen.